# TypeError: string indices must be integers while parsing JSON using Python?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am confuse now why I am not able to parse this JSON string. Similar code works fine on other JSON string but not on this one - I am trying to parse JSON String and extract script from the JSON.

Below is my code.

```
for step in steps:
    step_path = '/example/v1' +'/'+step

    data, stat = zk.get(step_path)
    jsonStr = data.decode("utf-8")
    print(jsonStr)
    j = json.loads(json.dumps(jsonStr))
    print(j)
    shell_script = j['script']
    print(shell_script)
```

So the first `print(jsonStr)` will print out something like this -

```
{"script":"#!/bin/bash\necho Hello world1\n"}
```

And the second `print(j)` will print out something like this -

```
{"script":"#!/bin/bash\necho Hello world1\n"}
```

And then the third print doesn't gets printed out and it gives this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test5.py", line 33, in <module>
    shell_script = j['script']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

So I am wondering what wrong I am doing here?

I have used same above code to parse the JSON and it works fine..

Comment: what is the expected output for the third time?

Comment: It should extract the script portion from the JSON string.. so it should print out `#!/bin/bash\necho Hello world1\n`. Right?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try replacing `j = json.loads(json.dumps(jsonStr))` with `j = json.loads(jsonStr)`.

Comment: Probably `j` was the same as `jsonStr`, a string. Indexing that with a string key fails with the exception you describe. Leaving out the `dumps` call makes the `loads` call turn the original string into a dictionary, which then you were able to index by key. If you turned your `print(j)` call into `print(repr(j))` you'll be able to see the difference.

Comment: I don't understand. when I try to do `json.loads(string_value)` it does and IMHO it should raise a `ValueError Exception: No JSON object could be decoded` as string_value is just a string not a JSON object.

Comment: @tMJ: If `jsonStr` is a string representing an object in JSON, then `json.dumps(jsonStr)` is a string representing (a string representing an object in JSON) in JSON. That's perfectly valid, but when you `loads` it, you get back a string representing an object in JSON; you'd have to `loads` it twice to get back the original object.

Comment: @abarnert So is the value returned from the call `zk.get`, is actually a JSON object?

Comment: @tMJ: There's no such thing as "a JSON object". When people say that, half the time they mean "a Python (or JavaScript or whatever) object that can be encoded in JSON", and half the time they mean "a string which is the JSON representation of an object". I have no idea which one you mean. I suspect you don't either. Just don't use that term. Obviously the value returned by `zk.get` is a `bytes` object, because you can call `.decode('utf-8')` on it. Presumably it's the UTF-8 encoding of a string that's the JSON representation of an object.

Comment: @tMJ: Meanwhile, if you don't understand why `json.loads(json.dumps(jsonStr))` is wrong, see [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6PwsyHwQ), and work through some similar examples yourself in the interactive shell and/or log out some reprs and types from your actual code to see what's what.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah, I meant the second. Ok! Thanks. `Presumably it's the UTF-8 encoding of a string that's the JSON representation of an object.`

Answer (score 58):

The problem is that jsonStr is a string that encodes some object in JSON, not the actual object.

You obviously *knew* it was a string, because you called it `jsonStr`. And it's proven by the fact that this line works:

```
jsonStr = data.decode("utf-8")
```

So, `jsonStr` is a string. Calling `json.dumps` on a string is perfectly legal. It doesn't matter whether that string was the JSON encoding of some object, or your last name; you can encode that string in JSON. And then you can decode that string, getting back the original string.

So, this:

```
j = json.loads(json.dumps(jsonStr))
```

… is going to give you back the exact same string as `jsonStr` in `j`. Which you still haven't *decoded* to the original object.

To do that, just don't do the extra encode:

```
j = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

If that isn't clear, try playing with it an interactive terminal:

```
>>> obj = ['abc', {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
>>> type(obj)
list
>>> obj[1]['b']
2
>>> j = json.dumps(obj)
>>> type(j)
str
>>> j[1]['b']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
>>> jj = json.dumps(j)
>>> type(jj)
str
>>> j
'["abc", {"a": 1, "b": 2}]'
>>> jj
'"[\\"abc\\", {\\"a\\": 1, \\"b\\": 2}]"'
>>> json.loads(j)
['abc', {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
>>> json.loads(j) == obj
True
>>> json.loads(jj)
'["abc", {"a": 1, "b": 2}]'
>>> json.loads(jj) == j
True
>>> json.loads(jj) == obj
False
```

Comment: Up Voted: Because you did more than just say replace a with b... You explained a little as to why and tried to show examples on how to debug..

Answer (score 11):

Ok... So for people who are still lost because they are used to JS this is what I understood after having tested multiple use cases :

- `json.dumps` does not make your string ready to be loaded with `json.loads`. It will only *encode* it to JSON specs (by adding escapes pretty much everywhere) !
- `json.loads` will transform a correctly formatted JSON string to a python dictionary. It will only work if the JSON follows the JSON specs (no single quotes, uppercase for boolean's first letter, etc).

### Dumping JSON - An encoding story

Lets take an example !

```
$ obj = {"foobar": True}
```

This is NOT json ! This is a python dictionary that uses python types (like booleans).

`True` is not compatible with the JSON specs so in order to send this to an API you would have to serialize it to **REAL** JSON. That's where `json.dumps` comes in !

```
$ json.dumps({"foobar": True})
'{"foobar": true}'
```

See ? `True` became `true` which is real JSON. You now have a string that you can send to the real world. Good job.

### Loading JSON - A decoding story

So now lets talk about `json.loads`.

You have a string that looks like json but its only a string and what you want is a python dictionary. Lets walk through the following examples :

```
$ string = '{"foobar": true}'
$ dict = json.loads(string)
{'foobar': True}
```

Here we have a string that looks like JSON. You can use `json.loads` to transform this string in dictionary and do `dict["foobar"]` which will return `True`.

*So, why so many errors ?*

Well, if your JSON looks like JSON but is not really JSON compatible (spec wise), for instance :

```
$ string = "{'foobar': true}"
$ json.loads(string)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
```

BAM ! This is not working because JSON specs wont allow you to have single quotes but only double ones...
If you reverse the quotes to `'{"foobar": true}'` then it will work.

What you probably have tried is :

```
string = json.loads(json.dumps("{'foobar': true}"))
```

This JSON is invalid (check the quotes) and moreover you'll get a string as a results. Disapointed ? I know...

- `json.dumps` WILL fix you JSON string but will also encode it. The encoding will render `json.loads` useless even if the JSON is now good to go.

**You have to understand that `json.dumps` encodes and `json.loads` decodes !**

So what you did here is encode a string and then decode the string. But its still a string ! you haven't done anything to change that fact ! If you want to get it from *string* to *dictionary* then you need an extra step... => **A second `json.loads` !**

Lets try that with a valid JSON (no mean single quotes)

```
$ obj = json.loads(json.loads(json.dumps('{"foobar": true}')))
$ obj["foobar"]
True
```

The json string went through `json.dumps` and got encoded. Then it when through `json.loads` where it got decoded (useless...YEAY). Finaly, it went through `json.loads` AGAIN and got transformed from string to dictionary. As you can see, using `json.dumps` only adds a useless step in that situation.

One last thing. If we do the same thing again but with a bad JSON:

```
$ string = json.loads(json.loads(json.dumps("{'foobar': true}")))
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes
```

Quotes are wrong here (ain't you getting used to this by now ?).
What happend here is that `json.dumps` fixed your JSON. `json.loads` removed the fix (lol) and finaly `json.loads` got the bad JSON which did not change as the first 2 steps canceled each other.

### TL;DR

In conclusion :
Fix you JSON yourself ! Don't give to `json.loads` wrongly formated JSON and don't try to mix `json.loads` with `json.dumps` to fix what only you can fix.
Hope this helped someone ;-)

Disclaimer. I'm no python expert.
Feel free to challenge this answer in the comment section.