# Unable to parse json string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json

Unable to parse data

I just printed `data = json.loads(somepostmessage)`

Output of data:

```
{'number': 'INC0010021', 'title': 'ghjghjgh', 'description': 'test creating sericenow tickets through post', 'state': 'New', 'priority': 'Planning', 'assigned_to': '', 'caller_id': ''}
```

Code:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.body)
    print(json.loads(request.body))
    print(type(json.loads(request.body)))
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    print(data['number'])
    return Response({"message": "Data mismatching"})
```

I was trying to parse through it `data['number']`:

```
Error: String indices must be integers
```

Comment: Has your data variable loaded as a dictionary or a string? What does `type(data)` give you? Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20085477/6144626) to get a better understanding of how to read json data using that library.

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: hi @AriCooper-Davis Type is <class 'str'>

Comment: hi @balderman if request.method == 'POST':
            print(request.body)
            print(json.loads(request.body))
            print(type(json.loads(request.body)))
        return Response({"message": "Data mismatching"})

Comment: Vyshnavi: Please [edit] your question and add the code to it.

Comment: @martineau can you check once I edited the code

Comment: Vyshnavi:  I don't think the code was formatting properly and you deleted some important information. I tried to correct both of these issues, but am not sure about the code because it doesn't make sense (so I may have indented it wrong). I also don't understand how you can show the data output but claim the `loads()` is causing the error. The output is Python syntax, not proper JSON.

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(json.loads(request.body)))` ? I believe the answer is 'str' and not 'dict'

Comment: what is the output of `request.POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally dawned on me what's wrong — it's because the `json.loads(request.body)` is returning a string, not a dictionary, which you assign to variable `data`. Following that you try to access `data['number']`, but since `data` is a string not a dictionary which cannot be indexed with a string like the former can be.

It seems strange (and might be a security risk, so there's probably a better way), but this seems like it might work (untested):

```
import ast
...
data = ast.literal_eval(json.loads(request.body))
```

Comment: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 26 (char 25)

Comment: Vyshnavi: Hmm, there's no double quotes in the data output shown in your question. Please edit your question again and replace it with what `print(request.body)` displays.