# Why is my PaymentMethod ID not detected when I run my AWS stripe application via Docker?

Tags: visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, http-post, stripe-payments

I am learning web development and I am currently working on creating a lambda test application for stripe. The paymentMethod id from the front-end is not being detected by my lambda function when I run it locally by calling `sam local start-api`.  I am doing my development on VS Code.

I followed the instructions on [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously) page to create and run my application. My directory structure looks like this:

[image]

`hello_world/app.py` has my Lambda function.

The code for invoking the lambda end-point in `script.js`looks like this:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_DIGITS'); 
var elements = stripe.elements();

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  // We don't want to let default form submission happen here,
  // which would refresh the page.
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createPaymentMethod({
    type: 'card',
    card: cardElement,
    billing_details: {
      // Include any additional collected billing details.
      name: 'Jenny Rosen',
    },
  }).then(stripePaymentMethodHandler);
});

function stripePaymentMethodHandler(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Show error in payment form
  } else {
    // Otherwise send paymentMethod.id to your server (see Step 4)
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/payment', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id,
      })
    }).then(function(result) {
      // Handle server response (see Step 4)
      result.json().then(function(json) {
        handleServerResponse(json);
      })
    });
  }
}
```

I ran the application on the browser by doing this:
[image]

When I click on `Pay` from my browser I can see the response in the logs on my dashboard:

[image]

The following code is for my lambda function `app.py`:

```
import json
import stripe
import requests
import logging

stripe.api_key= "sk_test_DIGITS"

def process_payment(event, context):
    try:
           print("START PRINTING")
           print(event)
           print("END PRINTING")
            intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
                payment_method = 'event["body"]["payment_method_id"]',
                amount = 1555,
                currency = 'usd',
                confirmation_method = 'automatic',
                confirm = True,
                payment_method_types=["card"]
                )
            return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps({
                'clientSecret': intent['client_secret'],
                # "location": ip.text.replace("\n", "")
            }),
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return {
        "statusCode": 400,
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": str(e),
            # "location": ip.text.replace("\n", "")
        }),
    }
```

My `template.yaml` is as follows:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 30

Resources:
  StripePaymentProcessor:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
        CodeUri: hello_world/
        Handler: app.process_payment
        Runtime: python3.6
        Events:
            Payment:  
              Type: Api
              Properties:
                Path: /payment
                Method: post


Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Payment function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/payment/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Payment Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt StripePaymentProcessor.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Payment function"
    Value: !GetAtt StripePaymentProcessorRole.Arn
```

While keeping the browser window open, I ran the `sam build` command and it worked properly. After that I ran the `sam local invoke` command and it produced the following output:

[image]

**I do not understand why `event` is empty. Should it not show the JSON data that got produced when I hit the pay button?**

To do some trouble-shooting, I ran `sam local start-api`, invoked the `POST` method on Postman by pasting the JSON body from my Stripe logs:

[image]

What I did on Postman makes no sense to me and the snippet above raised another question for me. **I do not understand why I see `"message": "string indices must be integers"` as a response on Postman.**

EDIT:

After following wcw's suggestion I edited my fetch code to look like this:

[image]

I did not not see any written matter on the console by changing my code in this way.

I am keeping the browser open via the command prompt and I ran `sam local start-api` via the VS code console to keep `http://127.0.0.1:3000/payment` open. When I clicked on the pay button, I got the following response:

[image]

So the image above seems to indicate that the lambda function is not detecting the paymentmethod body.

Comment: The `string indices must be integers` most likely due to `payment_method = 'event["body"]["payment_method_id"]',` wher event["body"] is not a JSON but a JSON string. You might need to parse it to use it as an object? 
Also for stripe.js code, can you debug or print out the `result.paymentMethod` in console to see if is contains the payment method result?

Comment: @wsw I followed your suggestion to display messages on the console but I did not see anything. Additionally, when I clicked on the pay button after running `sam local start-api`, I got the `403` error which I have also shown in my question.

Comment: @wsw Seems to be an issue with CORS. Irrespective of that, I do not understand why my messages are not appearing on the console. PS. I have very little experience with JS.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20085477/6525712) answer was very useful for me for debugging issues with JSON.

Comment: This problem is now solved. It was occurring because CORS was not enabled.

Comment: awesome, thanks for sharing @a_sid